# I am trying to use Eclipse to create a button from one activity to another but it doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having an issue with my code. I am new to development. I am trying to use one button to move from one of my activities to another. Please find the code below.

I keep getting the below Error:

```
06-03 15:25:45.117: W/dalvikvm(2410): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ktacknowledge.mysweetmessages/com.ktacknowledge.mysweetmessages.Home}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at com.ktacknowledge.mysweetmessages.Home.onCreate(Home.java:19)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-03 15:25:45.127: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     ... 11 more
```

Home Java

```
package com.ktacknowledge.mysweetmessages;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Home extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    ImageButton yourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    switchImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, SweetMessage.class);
            startActivity(i);
                            }
    });         
    }
```

Activity 2

```
package com.ktacknowledge.mysweetmessages;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


public class SweetMessage extends Activity {



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sweet_message);


    }
}
```

Home xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ktacknowledge.mysweetmessages.Home"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

  <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton4"
android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />
```

Comment: line 19 of Home class you have tried to cast `Button` to `ImageButton`, fix that

Comment: if you've cast the right type (Button-Button / ImageButton-ImageButton) and the error is still the same, clean and re-build your project

Comment: I have posted my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems that you are using ImageButton in your view (in your respective view's xml) but defining the same in your correponding java class as Button,do it as follows and your problem shall be solved. :)

if you want to use ImageButton define it as

```
ImageButton yourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonId);
```

if you want to use Button define it as

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
```

Answer (score 4):

your logcat says that you are doing wrong typecasting.you are trying to cast a button into imagebutton:

## Wrong:

```
Button _button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
```

## Correct:

```
Button _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your logcat, I am sure that you are trying to cast a `Button` from a `ImageButton` that you have defined in the xml file.

You can either change you `ImageButton` to `Button` in xml file else do the vice-versa.

Comment: I now get an error with  switchImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() is that the incorrect way to refer to the action?

Comment: As per your edited code, it is correct now.But what error you are getting now ?

Comment: all good i managed to get it working by changing the code abit